# Nginx redirect http to custom https AND https to custom https

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

I have a server on a restricted vps. I only have access to port 80, and some higher ports - no 443.

I was able to redirect all http to https on port 11111 [with return 301], OR redirect https request made on port 443 to 11111 [with error_page 497].

I would like to redirect http to https on custom port, and 'redirect' https to https custom port. I cannot listen on 443.

This is what I have so far:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.org;
    return 301   https://$server_name:11111$request_uri;

    #error_page 497 https://$server_name:11111$request_uri;
}
server{
    # SSL configuration
    #
      listen 11111 ssl default_server;
      listen [::]:11111 ssl default_server;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you cannot listen to port 443, you can't tell browser to do anything.

Comment: Well, when I used

    error_page 497 https://$server_name:11111$request_uri;

https request to port 443 got redirected to 11111. What I want, is to have this, and also http to https redirect.